# Scikit-Learn Decision Tree and Gaussian Process in Leaf

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, gaussian-process

How can I implement a decision tree which performs a Gaussian Process classification in the leafs? I want to do that in the context of an image segmentation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with what you've done so far.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any clue how to start.

Comment: StackOverflow may not be appropriate then. As an example, the [tag:machine-learning] tag recommends that StackOverflow is for implementation questions, and that theoretical or methodological questions are more appropriate on [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)